# Filtering a lookup column value of dxdatagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I am working with a devextreme mobile application, and I am not able to implement filter in one of my lookup column.

I want to filter lookup value based on my column data. For example: If my lookup column contains values like:

```
CEO,
Executive,
developer
```

Then while inserting a new row the look up should not contain these values .
I have attached a sample fiddler for better understanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLLastox/9/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can specify the `positions` as the [dataSource configuration object](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Configuration/). It allows you to set `filter` for the lookup data source:

```
var positions = {
    store: [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "CEO"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "   Sales Assistant"
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
       "Name": "    HR Manager"
    }, {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "   IT Manager"
    }, {
        "ID": 5,
        "Name": "   Shipping Manager"
    }],
    filter: null
};
```

Then, you will be able to configure the `filter` according to your case.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your concept....Can you please do the same with the sample I have provided.

Comment: Hello,I think you didn't got my requirement properly .My requirement is:                                 If my lookup column contains any value then the same value should be filtered out from my lookup drop-down while inserting